# Maze: Pentagonal Florets

Tags: mazes, network

Start at C, and visit all the letters!  No road is travelled twice, but some nodes might be (though, none which are labelled).  Special prizes for low score routes!

This is going for fun rather than hard.

I could have worked a bit more on this, but it should still be fun.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Crips, fresh winter snowflakes!
>  [image]